# Best practice for a sub-menu in mobile

Tags: navigation, menu, mobile-web, navigation-drawer

I'm a new UI designer and I'm trying to figure out how to make a sub-menu in mobile for an employer profile.

So basically the company/employer profile is like a LinkedIn approach but I'm having a hard time to figure out how to display the sub menu in mobile viewport.

I will attach the sketch that I did on what we are trying to aim in desktop and then mobile.

[image]

So what you can see, the employer have a horizontal menu below their banner (overview, jobs, culture, etc). Then on the sketch, under the Culture have it's sub content (not sure the term) but the gist is under it there will be sub-menu (Graduate stories, perks & benefits, etc).

So my problem here is how to show the sub-menu in the mobile viewport... Should I make a hamburger menu for sub-menu?

Or does anyone have better suggestions? Hope everything is clear.

Comment: Does the submenu have only 4 items? If yes, make icons and captions for desktop and just icons for mobile

Comment: What is the hamburger you have on top right of the mobile version for? Is it the same menu or did you forget a menu in the desktop wireframe?

Comment: Hi @Devin, that’s the main header navigation menu.

Comment: Hi @Danielillo, it depends.. sometimes it goes up to 6 submenu items..

Comment: so you missed a menu in desktop? You have one in desktop then you have 2 on mobile, the answer to this question makes a huge difference in the answer to you.

Comment: No sorry @Devin. I only forgotten to include the header menus in the desktop. Basically, we have a header menu, and when you go through an employer profile, there’s a navigation menu to browse their content. And under those menu, there are another sub menu. (Eg: Culture > Graduate storie, perks and benefits, events, team nembers, diversity, etc)

Comment: Here is how I do this: https://nav.go4webdev.org

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to create an experience that is similar to LinkedIn then you should start with a similar approach as LinkedIn on mobile, although they may also not have a consistent experience between mobile web and a native app (or cross-platform app).

However, you need to work out whether this approach is suitable for your users, and you can do that by research and testing activities.